# Aiohttp try while request isn't success

Tags: python, aiohttp

I have that code

```
async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
    content = 'none'
    while content == 'none':
        try:
            async with session.get(url) as resp:
                resp.raise_for_status()
                content = await resp.json()
        except aiohttp.ClientError:
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
```

I want make request while result is good, but if i compile this, sometimes result is 'none'. How make it better.

Answer (score 3):

I use [`async-retrying`](https://pypi.org/project/async_retrying/) for that. You mark the request function with the `@retry` decorator and it will be re-run if an exception is raised. Example:

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp
from async_retrying import retry


@retry(attempts=100)
async def req(session, url):
    async with session.get(url) as resp:
        resp.raise_for_status()
        return await resp.json()


async def main():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        payload = await req(session, "http://eu.httpbin.org/get")
        print("payload received:", payload)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```